# Regular Expression using Python

Tags: python, regex

Please help me fix this regular expression check.

```
x=re.match('^(\d{3})\s\d{3}-\d{4}$','(800) 325-3535')
```

It is supposed to return match object but what I get is None value.
Am I doing anything wrong over here. Please help.

Comment: And it is supposed to match what? What is the input?

Comment: @Gwenc37 Phone numbers in the format as (800) 325-3535

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should escape the `()` by backslash:

```
^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

Like this:

```
x = re.match('^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$','(800) 325-3535')
```

`()` means capturing groups in regex and whatever symbol has a special meaning in regex should be escaped to be used in its literal form.